# jQuery function called by Generic Javascript function

Tags: jquery, javascript

I'm a bit confused it seems here. What I'm trying to do is create a Javascript function that disables all inputs on a page, and then a function that enables all the inputs on a page.

This was pretty easy with jQuery. My question is, how can I wrap these jQuery functions in a traditional JS function? The reason I need to do this is because I'm calling these functions using ActionScript. Put another way, I don't understand how I can write jQuery code and then call it in a tradition Javascript function call manner.

Works great, but isn't wrapped in a function...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(':input').attr('disabled', "disabled");
});
```

Wrapped in a function and doesn't work at all, what am I doing wrong here??

```
function init_lock_test(){
    $(':input').attr('disabled', "disabled");
}
```

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? When/how are you calling `init_lock_test`?

Comment: Actually, your first example /is/ written in a function. The function is added to JQuery's ready() method, which adds the function to the list of functions to be automagically executed once the document is done loading. I'm pretty sure you're not calling your `init_lock_test()` method anywhere, meaning the actual method isn't executed either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't *directly* call JavaScript functions in a web page from ActionScript, and there's no special thing as a "jQuery function." You should be [using ActionScript's ExternalInterface](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html?filter_flex=4.1&filter_flashplayer=10.1&filter_air=2) to call the JavaScript function indirectly:

```
import flash.external.ExternalInterface

// Calls the function init_lock_test
ExternalInterface.call("init_lock_test");
```

Comment: I'm well aware of the ExternalInterface class, I'm just trying to write a javascript function that can be called by the function. The problem I'm having is that I don't have a strong background in javascript and jquery. So this doesn't really address my question.

Comment: @Ryan. How does this not address your question. I'm pretty sure his code will work if wrapped your jquery code with a `functon init_lock_test () {...}` If it's not working, write exactly what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I'd avoid using jQuery for this, because it's not really needed :p
Try this:

```
function lockInputs(lock) {
    var tags, elems, i, j;
    tags = ['input','button','textarea'];
    for( i=0; i<tags.length; i++) {
        elems = document.getElementsByTagName(tags[i]);
        for( j=0; j<elems.length; j++) {
            if( lock) elems[j].setAttribute("_lock",elems[j].disabled);
            elems[j].disabled = lock || elems[j].getAttribute("_lock");
        }
    }
}
```

That should disable all input fields with lockInputs(true); and re-enable them with lockInputs(false);
It also saves the disabled state, so any that were disabled to start with stay that way.
HTH!

Comment: You don't want `select` locked?

Comment: That's a lot of code for a simple query. And you're going to duplicate the logic every time you need something like it again. I don't like to inject jquery into questions, but this was tagged as jquery, no need for a less elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping jquery within a traditional js function really is as easy as your `init_lock_test` function.  You must have an issue with invoking your function from ActionScript.  Try this to verify:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  init_lock_test();
});
```

Comment: or simply, `$(init_lock_test)`